# Unable to perform action on accessibilitynodeinfo

Tags: android, accessibility

> Fatal exception: main Process: com.example.acxessibility, pid: 18375
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform action on sealed
> instance. at
> android.view.acxessiblity.AccessiblityNodeInfo.enforceNotSealed(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3743)

Occur on

```
Node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessiblityAction.ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN.getId());
```

Comment: Put your whole code so we can understand.

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo?hl=en#performAction(int,%20android.os.Bundle) this method throws exception,if it call outtside of accessibility service.